# How to use reflection to invoke method in public members of a class in java?

Tags: java, reflection

Class A:

```
public class A {
    public B b;

    public A(String s) {
        b = new B(s);
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {
    String s;

    public B(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void printB() {
        System.out.println(this.s);
    }
}
```

So i want to use reflection in java in order to create class A and use his public member B  in order to run printB method using reflection with a given string from client 'printB'

How should i do it?

Comment: yes i did. @MadProgrammer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to, but as a proof of concept...

```
package myPackage;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName("myPackage.Test$a");
            Constructor con = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
            Object instanceOfA = con.newInstance("A value");
            Field bField = clazz.getField("b");
            Object instanceOfB = bField.get(instanceOfA);
            Method printBMethod = instanceOfB.getClass().getMethod("printB");
            printBMethod.invoke(instanceOfB);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchFieldException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class a {

        public B b;

        public a(String s) {
            b = new B(s);
        }
    }

    public static class B {

        String s;

        public B(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public void printB() {
            System.out.println(this.s);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just having a class with few members that each of them implements around of different 50-60 methods i split it to few class in order to prevent of having 1 class with 300 methods. now i'm getting the command from remote client and i need to invoke the requested method